# How to reset font size in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, unity, fonts

After my last update and restart ubuntu changed the font size to a very small one! How can I change it back to normal?

[image]

as you can see over the red it is very small

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset gnome font configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4989/reset-gnome-font-configuration)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd install `unity-tweak-tool` and use the "Restore defaults" in the Fonts tab:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could try installing dconf-editor.  This will give you access to a lot of "under-the-hood" settings.  In dconf-editor go to org -> gnome -. desktop -> interface ... and then set the scalng-factor to 1.  Also set text-scaling-factor to 1.  Make a note of the current settings before you change them so you can always put them back the way you found them if you want to.  Unfortunately I'm not allowed to post a screenshot as I've only just joined the site!