# IntelliJ Bad Font Rendering

Tags: fonts, antialiasing, intellij

I've recently installed IntelliJ on my Ubuntu system and realized that the font I want to normally use `Monaco` doesn't render properly in IntelliJ. So, the problem was slightly fixed from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/496381) post however the editor would still not render properly with `Monaco`;

This is currently the state of my IDE:

[image]

Comment: Maybe my **[answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/455262/181228)** will helpful for you.

Comment: @DozortsevAnton Thanks, but all solutions mentioned there didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I actually figured it out with some research and playing around; heres how you can do it on your side:

Requirements:

1. Stable Internet connection
2. Root access to your system

Steps:

We first need to install [TuxJDK](https://code.google.com/p/tuxjdk/):

1. Go on the link above and download the JDK;
2. Once downloaded the JDK extract the folder named `jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08`;
3. We're now going to move the folder into /usr/lib/ using Terminal

```
sudo mv FOLDERPATH /usr/lib/
```

Then, we're going to get IntelliJ to use TuxJDK:

1. Go to your IntelliJ path;
2. Then go into `IDEAPATH/bin`;
3. Edit idea.sh using nano or gedit;

   ```
   sudo nano idea.sh
   ```
4. Go all the way down and you should see a command starting with `eval` you want to change that command to this:

```
eval "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08/bin/java" $ALL_JVM_ARGS -Djb.restart.code=88 $MAIN_CLASS_NAME "$@"
```

5. Save the file and open up IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: At least as of the IntelliJ EAP 15 (don't know about earlier) you can just point intellij at your TuxJDK install using the IDEA_JDK env var, like: export IDEA_JDK=/usr/lib/jdk-8u25-tuxjdk-b01/ & idea.sh

Comment: Where to get jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08.tar.xz ? Download link at https://code.google.com/p/tuxjdk/ is not working.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a little manual howto fix this.

`wget http://urshulyak.com:8001/index.php/s/P4afbWaX3mvyjP7/download &&
tar -zxvf jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08.tar.gz &&
sudo mv jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08 /usr/lib/jvm &&
rm jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08.tar.gz`

Script to start Intellij Idea

*only note that need to change IDEA_HOME location for your path of idea

```
#!/bin/sh

IDEA_HOME=/opt/idea
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8u5-tuxjdk-b08/
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd \
                      -Dsun.java2d.xrender=true"
export GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
exec $IDEA_HOME/bin/idea.sh "$@"
```

More info and screenshots of better fonts: http://urshulyak.com/page/show/2
Result:
[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Could you please update the link? wget gives connection refused when trying to download tuxjdk.

Comment: And the changes in tuxjdk are?

Comment: Nope, no changes, just added the all in one command for easy download

Comment: I've put exports directly to <idea path>/bin/idea.sh (only without last `exec...` command). It works too. Thanks!

Comment: wget stucks on connecting. :(

Comment: try do wget again

Comment: @Yaroslav Urshulyak please fix the link - it does not work. UPD: Sorry, in fact it's corporate proxy - refuses connections on non-standard ports. With TorBrowser I was able to download it, thanks.