# Popup fonts in IntelliJ IDEA are too large, or bold/pixelated, 15.04 using tuxjdk

Tags: unity, 15.04, java, fonts, intellij

Here's a screenshot showing the problem:

[image]

As you can see, where the autocomplete text exceeds the size of the popup, the font becomes strange. Similarly, the popup window has text much larger than anywhere else in the application.

What I've done so far:

My fonts were aliased and nasty at first, but [following this answer fixed them](https://askubuntu.com/a/496381/454168) (other than my current problem) - the only difference is that I used [the latest tuxjdk from here](https://code.google.com/p/tuxjdk/) (jdk-8u25-tuxjdk-b01.tar.xz) like [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/503132/454168).

I had also [tried this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/455262/454168)
which as commenters say, broke system fonts, so I reversed the changes and followed [the recommended answer here to fix that](https://askubuntu.com/a/500541/454168).

I have set my "Override default fonts by" setting in IntelliJ IDEA to "Ubuntu" size 12, as otherwise ALL fonts in the IDE are huge. I use a different font in the editor window, but using the same font as the default, or even trying other fonts, has no effect on this issue.

Is this possible to fix, or am I just going to have to put up with it?

Comment: I am suprised that no other people even upvoted this problem.