# How can I use Monaco Linux True Type Font in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: 18.04, fonts, intellij

IntelliJ IDEA (version 2018.3.3) doesn't see the Monaco Linux font I installed despite all other programs being able to. I've tried using the solutions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454361/font-in-intellij-idea-on-ubuntu-14-04) but they either don't work, they're dangerous (breaks fonts in Ubuntu 14), or they're for other systems.

How can I get IntelliJ to use the font I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue. Solved it by using different types of TTF files of Monaco fonts. You can find them on [GitHub](https://github.com/probil/Monaco-IDE-font).

Comment: Glad! That's works. Monaco is Love BTW.